# When using mpirun with R script, should I copy manually file/script on clusters?

Tags: r, foreach, mpi, cluster-computing

I'm trying to understand how openmpi/mpirun handle script file associated with an external program, here a R process ( doMPI/Rmpi )

I can't imagine that I have to copy my script on each host before running something like :

```
mpirun --prefix /home/randy/openmpi -H clust1,clust2 -n 32 R --slave -f file.R
```

But, apparently it doesn't work until I copy the script 'file.R' on clusters, and then run mpirun. Then, when I do this, the results are written on cluster, but I expected that they would be returned to working directory of localhost.

Is there another way to send R job from localhost to multiple hosts, including the script to be evaluated ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's surprising that mpirun doesn't know details of how scripts are specified to commands such as "R", but the Open MPI version of mpirun does include the `--preload-files` option to help in such situations:

```
--preload-files <files>
     Preload the comma separated list of files to the current working
     directory  of  the  remote  machines  where  processes  will  be
     launched prior to starting those processes.
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't get it to work, which may be because I misunderstood something, but I suspect it isn't well tested because very few use that option since it is quite painful to do parallel computing without a distributed file system.

If `--preload-files` doesn't work for you either, I suggest that you write a little script that calls scp repeatedly to copy the script to the cluster nodes. There are some utilities that do that, but none seem to be very common or popular, which I again think is because most people prefer to use a distributed file system. Another option is to setup an sshfs file system.

Comment: Thanks ! It doesn't work with `--preload-files`. Strange ! So, for now, I will use a script to scp my code on each nodes. Same for data. But I will definitely ask the sys admin to install sshfs, it's a simple and clean method.